# Compare .NET execution to Mono (on OSX)

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monomac

I built an application in .NET and works great. I'm currently in the process of making a Mono port for OSX but have come across a very weird bug. In one area of my code it seems to output completely different data on Mono than on .NET yet as far as I can tell by stepping through the code myself all everything executes identically, though I could easily miss something. What I'd like is some way to execute both programs and have the "execution" saved so that I can compare the two in something like Beyond Compare.

Comment: Very unclear what you are looking for: you already compared your programs and got different results - do you need help in comparing the results?

Comment: Can you drill down the code which is yielding different result and paste the code here?

Comment: I would but the code is highly intertwined, I'd have to post thousands of line. That's part of my problem, odds are in all that I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to do execute programs and the compare the executions after they've completed.

What I would do is to put the Mac and PC next to eachother, and run the debuggers simultaneously. Then you should easily be able to compare each execution and find out where they start to differ.

Comment: Thats what I've been trying. I've noticed no difference but I'm only human :)

Comment: @SamuelEngland: You did notice that the data output at some point is different - try backtracking from there to see where it starts being different.